# Output of my three layer neural network is NAN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have written a simple three layer neural network without any optimization or cost minimization. I am only initializing the weights of Neural Network and then feed forwarding to have the output. Here is my code.

```
def create_placeholders(n_x, n_y):
    #n_x -- scalar, size of an image vector (num_px * num_px = 64 * 64 * 3 = 12288)
    #n_y -- scalar, number of classes (from 0 to 5, so -> 6)

    X = tf.placeholder(shape=[n_x, None],dtype=tf.float32)
    Y = tf.placeholder(shape=[n_y, None],dtype=tf.float32)
    return X, Y
```

Now parameter initialization.

```
def initialize_parameters():
    tf.set_random_seed(1)                  
    W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", [25,1269], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
    b1 = tf.get_variable("b1", [25,1], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
    W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", [12, 25], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
    b2 = tf.get_variable("b2", [12, 1], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
    W3 = tf.get_variable("W3", [1, 12], initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(seed = 1))
    b3 = tf.get_variable("b3", [1, 1], initializer = tf.zeros_initializer())
    parameters = {"W1": W1,
                  "b1": b1,
                  "W2": W2,
                  "b2": b2,
                  "W3": W3,
                  "b3": b3}
    return parameters
```

now the important function for feed forward where I think there is some issue which is not giving the valid output.

```
def forward_propagation(X, parameters):
    W1 = parameters['W1']
    b1 = parameters['b1']
    W2 = parameters['W2']
    b2 = parameters['b2']
    W3 = parameters['W3']
    b3 = parameters['b3']

    Z1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W1,X),b1)                        # Z1 = np.dot(W1, X) + b1
    A1 = tf.nn.relu(Z1)                                    # A1 = relu(Z1)
    Z2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W2,A1),b2)                       # Z2 = np.dot(W2, a1) + b2
    A2 = tf.nn.relu(Z2)                                    # A2 = relu(Z2)
    Z3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(W3,A2),b3)                       # Z3 = np.dot(W3,Z2) + b3 it should be # Z3 = np.dot(W3,A2) + b3
    return Z3
```

Below is the code for session creation and running for session for my training data with a same `train_x_upsampled` and `train_y_upsampled`.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
X, Y = create_placeholders(n_x, n_y)
parameters = initialize_parameters()
Z = forward_propagation(X, parameters)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    X, Y, parameters, Z3 = sess.run([X, Y, parameters, Z], feed_dict={X: train_x_upsampled, Y: train_y_upsampled})
    print(Z3)
```

I Want to get the value of output for Z3 for the initialized parameters. Currently I am getting an invalid output.

```
[[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]]
```

Comment: You can try using [`tf.verify_tensor_all_finite`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/debugging_operations#verify_tensor_all_finite) to verify where the `NaN`s  are introduced.
Start at the input with `tf.verify_tensor_all_finite(X, "X contains NaN!")` and `tf.verify_tensor_all_finite(Y, "Y contains NaN!")` and move on from there layer by layer

Comment: Would you please guide me a little where do I insert this `tf.verify_tensor_all_finite` in my code? @GPhilo

Comment: You can put that anywhere, as long as it's before you create the `tf.Session`. For example, after you define the placeholders, you can put `X = tf.verify_tensor_all_finite(X, "X contains NaN!")` and the respective one for Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I identified the issue using `tf.verify_tensor_all_finite`. Two columns of my input training data contained `NAN` values which then in turn made the output of the whole network as `nan`. I identified those columns using the following peace of code.

```
ar_fulldata_input_norm.loc[:, ar_fulldata_input_norm.isnull().any()]
```

This will take `ar_fulldata_input_norm` as an input and give out only those columns which contains `NAN`values.

I want to point out that `nan` values were introduced in my training data because of the z-score normalization as originally in my data, two columns were completely zero in all rows. I deleted those two columns and the problem vanished away.